# Is there a way to have a floating action button do something dependant on which fragment is currently in nav host?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having some trouble with a single activity project. There is a floating action button in MainActivity that I want to use in several fragments. So if HomeFragment is in the nav_host_fragment, I want the floating action button to do thing1, and if SecondFragment is in nav_host_fragment, I want the floating action button to do thing2.

If you create a new project in android studio and select basic activity you'll get the code I'm working with.
There is a MainActivity, two fragments (FirstFragment and SecondFragment) and a Navigation controller. FirstFragment is displayed first, and this is where I want the action button to invoke method `doThing1()`. If you click on the button in this fragment it takes you to SecondFragment. If you click the floating action button now, I would like the fab to invoke `doThing2()`
How would I go about this?

I've tried

In the fragments

```
   public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);`
   
   view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(v -> {
   doThing1();
    });
```

But this doesn't work because `findViewById` doesn't find the fab, I guess because it's searching in the fragments own layout and not in the main activity.

The only way I solved this is by getting a reference to MainActivity in the fragment, invoke a public method from MainActivity and set a field (to "first" or something similar) and then in the fab onClick method check what this variable is set to and execute different methods dependant on this variable.

So in `onViewCreated`:

```
MainActivity reference = (MainActivity) getActivity();
assert reference != null;
reference.changeFabActionTo("thing2");
```

And then in the click listener

```
fab.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if(whichFragmentClick.equals("thing1")) {
                    // doThing1()}
                if(whichFragmentClick.equals("thing2")) {
                    // doThing2()}
            });
```

This doesn't seem like the way to go about this however, and I feel like this isn't the proper way.
Any ideas?

Comment: No, your way is totally fine. This is how you do it. (I'm not sarcastic)

Comment: @paladin surely there must be a better way? I've started looking into using ViewModels, aren't they sort of what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many possible solutions:

**Kotlin:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private lateinit var floatingButton: FloatingActionButton

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

    floatingButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    floatingButton.setOnClickListener { _ ->
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val visibleFragment = navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager?.fragments?.first()

        when (visibleFragment != null) {
          true -> {
            when (visibleFragment::class.java) {
              FirstFragment::class.java -> doStuff1()
              SecondFragment::class.java -> doStuff2()
              else -> doSomethingElse()
            }
          }
          false -> {
            println("<<<DEV>>> visibleFragment is not defined")
          }
        }
      }
  }

  private fun doStuff1() {
    println("<<<DEV>>> Fragment 1 is visible")
  }

  private fun doStuff2() {
    println("<<<DEV>>> Fragment 2 is visible")
  }

  private fun doSomethingElse() {
    println("<<<DEV>>> Fragment is undefined")
  }

  override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    return true
  }

  override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    return when (item.itemId) {
      R.id.action_settings -> true
      else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
  }
}
```

**Java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment navHostFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);

            if (navHostFragment instanceof NavHostFragment) {
                Fragment visibleFragment = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);

                if (visibleFragment instanceof FirstFragment) {
                    doStuff1();
                } else if (visibleFragment instanceof  SecondFragment) {
                    doStuff2();
                } else {
                    doSomethingElse();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void doStuff1() {
    System.out.println("<<<DEV>> Fragment 1 is visible");
}

public static void doStuff2() {
    System.out.println("<<<DEV>> Fragment 2 is visible");
}

public static void doSomethingElse() {
    System.out.println("<<<DEV>>> Fragment is undefined");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This looks exactly like what I want!
However, I don't understand kotlin, is there a way to convert this to java please?

Comment: You can convert Kotlin to Java using Android Studio. Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin's bytecode and press "Decompile". The result code will be not ideal, but understandable. @Davidtagt

Comment: I'm not an expert in Java, but I've updated my post and test code before posting. @Davidtagt

Comment: Thank you so much, this completely answered my question!

Answer (score 0):

You can have simple when(switch) and check latest fragment instance type, i